How to make rigify deform bone not move while control does by constraint
Is there a way to make the control bones just visually follow a constraint, but when deforming it does not?
I know there is a way only give a constraint to the control, but the DEF will follow because it is parented to it.
Example: I have a control bone that looks like an arrow, and it has a damped track constraint to a Suzanne, a mesh is parented to the arrow and I don´t want the rotation from the damped track constraint applyd to it.
This is just an example, not the problem it self, the actual thing I'm trying is a bit more complex.

Usually your controller bone isn't the one performing the deformation, the controller bone only influences, in some way, one or multiple deform bones. The general principle is, make the controller bone not influence the deform bone directly in order to have granular control over it. This can be done using constraints and intermediate bones, but the precise setup depends on the situation you are in and what you want to achieve precisely. If all you want is a controller bone that leads to no deformation in any way, then don't make it deform/influence deform bones.

I would simply create a copy of the control bone, and maybe set a Child of constraint on the original, targeting the new one, to animate the parent/child relationship (and therefore the deforming bones), but maybe you should explain better what you want to achieve, because the Rigify structure is quite complex and some properties (like parent-child bones) cannot be animated.
